# Why should Test methods in Junit be defined public?

Tags: junit, junit4

I was going through the documentation for junit tests but am unable to understand the need for defining tests as public.Could anyone share some info on this?

I read on https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/Test.java

But am still not clear with the reason.

With is I meant why can't I write something as

```
@Test
private void testAdd(){ }
```

Answer (score 10):

The JUnit framework calls your test methods from outside your test class. If your test methods are private, it won't be able to do that.

Comment: Got it!But another question that arises is:how do we hide any test method which we don't want to be accessed from outside our test class by other users?

Comment: @Jagori What's the use case for a private test method?  The purpose of a test method is to be run by the JUnit framework, so there's no use in having a private one. You can write private non-test methods in your test class that are then called by a test method if you need code that's not directly accessible from outside the class.

Comment: Usually tests are not included in published artifacts and therefore cannot be used.

Answer (score 6):

"Test classes, test methods, and lifecycle methods are not required to be public, but they must not be private."

Ref. the doc:
https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-classes-and-methods

Comment: This is true for JUnit 5, but not for JUnit 4 (which the question is tagged with). So if you want to write test methods that aren't public, consider upgrading to JUnit 5.

Answer (score 4):

JUnit accesses your test methods by reflection. A SecurityManager can control access to private methods. Hence JUnit uses only public methods and fields for anything that is accessed by the framework.

In short: JUnit would fail to run private test methods if a SecurityManager is active that does not allow access to private methods.

Comment: pardon me Stefan,but am not clear with this comment of yours.Could you elaborate on what you mean by Junit accessing test methods by reflection.

Comment: JUnit uses reflection to find all the methods that are annotated with @Test. (See computeTestMethods() in https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@Test
public void testAdd(){ }
```

your testAdd method is private, it won't be able to do that.

Comment: Yes,this was what I wanted to understand why only private and not public.I guess I got the answer since JUnit framework calls the test methods from outside test class hence it has to be defined as public.But another question that arises is:how do we hide any method which we dont want to be accessed from outside test class?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to hide test classes?